# How to close layered navigation accordion on side click?

Tags: magento2, layered-navigation, accordion, collapsible

If anyone can help me with how to close active accordion of layered navigation if clicked outside the layered navigation block?

```
 <div class="filter-options" id="narrow-by-list" data-role="content" data-mage-init='{"accordion":{"openedState": "active", "collapsible": true, "active": false, "multipleCollapsible": false}}'>
```

this is the default accordion which is collapsible.

Answer (score 1):

Got the solution.
Create a new js file and include it or edit any theme js file.
Add below code.

```
/*Close Layered Navigation on side click*/
$(document).click(function(e) {
    if (!$( "#narrow-by-list" ).is(e.target) && !$( "#narrow-by-list" ).has(e.target).length) {
        $(".filter-options-item").collapsible("deactivate");
    }
});
```